# Why does my phone reset the wallpaper to this CyanogenMod default image?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wallpaper

```
Note II - CM11 Nightly - KitKat 4.4.2
```

Every now and then, my phone will reset the wallpaper to this default one. It happens randomly and not even after a boot or any state changing event. It could be possible that an app crashes, and it resets the background, but that does not make much sense. If anyone can help me prevent from the wallpaper from changing, that would be fantastic.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This seems like a bug. Since this is a nightly build, have you considered contacting the maintainer for the ROM to report the issue?

Comment: One word: "Nightly". Nightly builds are inherently test builds and will be buggy. Contact the CM guys with a bug report! Any CM rom that is not a 'stable' will have issue. I'm finding CM + Samsung is a bad idea lately to be blunt.

Comment: This has been going on for a while. It went away when I upgraded from 10.2 to 11 (4.3 to 4.4), but now it's back. :| I haven't had any other issues with nightly builds. Have been running nightlies since the original Droid days.

Comment: I have been doing it for years myself, but I don't anymore. They've changed focus and many nightly builds are being done by random people not affiliated and some of the builds are shockingly bad quality. CM was my go-to ROM for years, but with my Samsung devices it's a no go. On the S4: Camera Issues, reboot issues, over heating, apps force closing, system UI crashing, poor call quality, compatability issues with Xposed framework and so on and so on. (There are MANY great people associated with CM, I'm not attacking them, but the Samsung nightlies are pants.)

Comment: @RossC - What do you use now? PA?

Comment: I was on PA, lovely stuff, moved to Echoe Illusion ROM, they did a 'Google Edition' KitKat ROM recently (The google edition S4 is basically a nexus running almost Stock). Haven't looked back. As always though I'd try a few and find what you like. PA is good, PAC is good, AOSP is great. Keep in mind WANAN XPOSED allows all the tweaking that indiviudal ROMs have (change DPI, PIE controls etc) so the need for fancy features is declining, and a good stable base is the way to go! I don't have a Note 2 though so not sure what's good on it!